# unsertUI with multiple=TRUE does not work for tabs in tabsetPanel in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am want to use functionality that parameter `multiple=TRUE` should provide in `insertUI` function to insert same UI on several tabs within `tabsetPanel`. According to description setting `multiple=TRUE` should insert the UI on every tab with the same id.
Unfortunately, it does not work for some reason - UI is inserted only on the first tab.

Minimal example code is below.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("add", "Add content")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = "tabs",
        tabPanel("panel1", div(id = "panel", "Panel 1 content")),
        tabPanel("panel2", div(id = "panel", "Panel 2 content")),
        tabPanel("panel3", div(id = "panel", "Panel 3 content"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    insertUI(selector = "#panel", multiple = TRUE, where = "beforeEnd",
             ui = p("added content"))
  })
}

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should bind it to the `id` of the `tabsetPanel`, also change it to `where = "afterEnd"`. Also make sure that all element ids are unique

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("add", "Add content")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = "tabs",
        tabPanel("panel1", div(id = "panel1", "Panel 1 content")),
        tabPanel("panel2", div(id = "panel2", "Panel 2 content")),
        tabPanel("panel3", div(id = "panel3", "Panel 3 content"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    insertUI(selector = "#tabs", multiple = TRUE, where = "afterEnd",
             ui = p("added content"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Alterintavely you need to crate the contect for each `tabPanel` `id`:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("add", "Add content")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = "tabs",
        tabPanel("panel1", div(id = "panel1", "Panel 1 content")),
        tabPanel("panel2", div(id = "panel2", "Panel 2 content")),
        tabPanel("panel3", div(id = "panel3", "Panel 3 content"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    lapply(1:3, function(i){
      insertUI(selector = paste0("#panel",i), multiple = TRUE, where = "afterEnd",
               ui = p("added content"))
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you. Using id of tabsetPanel as a selector for insertion adds content in front of the existing content. I wanted to add it after existing content on each tab (sorry, I did not specifically said that in the original question). The second code with the loop works and does not require multiple=TRUE (can be FALSE since all ids are unique). Would still be good to understand why multiple=TRUE does not work as intended in this case

Comment: Also, I wonder if calculation-wise looping is the same as multiple=TRUE if it works correctly.

Comment: its because the `ids` have to be unique within the page. I doubt that `multiple=TRUE` because then it has to lookup all the `tabPanel` `ids` in the background and do the same